# python server and node.js webclient connection

Tags: python, node.js

I made server to Python script that open port 22222 and not http protocol.
My client is made node.js(this system is http). And client has attempted connection to python server to 22222 port.`enter code here`
but it didn't connect.

example.

```
HTTP WEB CLIENT(PORT 80) REQUEST MESSAGE -> PYTHON SERVER (PORT 22222)
HTTP WEB CLIENT(PORT 80) <- PYTHON SERVER (PORT 22222) RESPONSE MESSAGE "1"
HTTP WEB CLIENT(PORT 80) <- PYTHON SERVER (PORT 22222) RESPONSE MESSAGE "2"
HTTP WEB CLIENT(PORT 80) <- PYTHON SERVER (PORT 22222) RESPONSE MESSAGE "3"
HTTP WEB CLIENT(PORT 80) <- PYTHON SERVER (PORT 22222) RESPONSE MESSAGE "4"
HTTP WEB CLIENT(PORT 80) <- PYTHON SERVER (PORT 22222) RESPONSE MESSAGE "connection closed"`enter code here`
```

is server(not http protocol) and client(http) impossible connection?

Answer (score 0):

If the two sides aren't speaking the same (or at least a similar) protocol then there's no way to communicate properly.

Answer (score 0):

If your Python server isn't speaking HTTP, you'll have to use Node's `net` module to talk to it, not Node's `http` module. HTTP is a well-defined protocol (set of rules about how clients and servers can talk to each other) and Node's `http` module assumes you're talking to a server that obeys HTTP rules. Since your server doesn't, you need to talk to it with a client that just knows how to speak TCP/IP (which Node's `net` module gives you), and you'll have to make it follow the protocol yourself.